# how to configure style for a className at a certain path on page?

Tags: css

I'm working on a page that has the same className set for a td in a thead as well as the td in the tbody (not a great design I know, but that's what I'm working with).   Anyway, I need to configure the style for the class name specifically at the tbody td level.  And more specifically, for the tbody td with class name _JobType.   The first part works (table tbody tr td) but the class name filter at the end isn't working.  What do I need to update with this class specifier to make it work?:

```
table tbody tr td _JobType{
    text-decoration: underline;
    div:hover{
        cursor:pointer !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the relevant `<td>` has a `_JobType` class?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]!